Transfer pointer from dll (c/c++) to python
I have a DLL written in C++ ( it can be rewritten in C ) and python code where I import the DLL with cdll.LoadLibrary(). Then I specify a function from DLL and it's agrument types. Then I call the function which returns double *. The pointer points to memory allocated somewhere in the heap — the function does some math and stores the result in 3500 x 8 array ( I allocate memory with new[] and don't free it in DLL function. I supposed to use that DLL with C++ code so I could free the memory somewhere in it ).
The question is. Is there a way I can receive double * from DLL and work with array, on which the pointer points? As I know, python has no implementation for pointers. Thank you!
P.S. As I know, default return type for DLL functions in Python is int. So can I work with 3500 x 8 data using it's int adress?

You are aware that cdll is an alias for ctypes.CDLL, which is the library for interfacing with memory directly? Ctypes very much does have infrastructure for reading memory through pointers. Furthermore, if you plan to use this with numpy or another Python array module, know that they often allow construction directly from a pointer and shape.

I have no idea about how capable python is in this respect but it doesn't matter. If you allocate something in a shared library, the same library should do the deallocation

Duplicate of [SO]: C function called from Python via ctypes returns incorrect value (@CristiFati's answer)? Also here's how to use such a pointer: [SO]: C++ & Python: Pass and return a 2D double pointer array from python to c++ (@CristiFati's answer).

@CristiFati thanks, link №2 is helpful! It solved my problem

@TedLyngmo thank you, I have added function for deallocation

@Botje yes I use ctypes. I am new to python so I didn't know that ctypes allow to read memory via pointers. Thank you! My issue is solved by now, I'm gonna for further reading on ctypes :)

you should try dll.your_function.restype = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double)

Thank you. As I am new to Python, I didn't know about POINTER() method !
